Bottom padding from super view swiftui
Question - screen below - i don't understand why do I have bottom padding for save button
my code is:
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.DesignSystem.background.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        Text("Save")
                            .font(.fontRegular(size: 20))
                            .tint(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.DesignSystem.blue)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    }
                
            }
            .background(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal, 80)
            .padding(.top, 12)
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    test()
        
}


I dont see from where comes bottom padding for save button, you can copy and run code and see for your self, there is nothing extra, is it some safe area?

@BenzyNeez having button outside a safe area is not a good idea. Instead it would be better to extend the background (like you said in first half of your comment), but not to move the button

@timbretimbre Agreed, added an answer that shows how this is done.

If you are talking about the black strip below the button then this is the safe area inset.
The black background of the VStack is filling this area because the background is applied using .background(), which ignores the safe area inset by default - see background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:).
If you add .ignoresSafeArea() to the VStack then this causes the complete VStack to move down and touch the bottom of the screen. However, this means the button is mainly in the safe area inset, which is not a very good solution.
A better approach might be to allow the button itself to extend to the bottom of the screen and cover the safe area inset, but leaving the same height of button above the inset as before. To achieve this, apply the clip shape and .ignoresSafeArea() to the background of the button (in this order):
Button {
} label: {
    Text("Save")
        .font(.fontRegular(size: 20))
        .tint(.white)
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(
            Color.DesignSystem.blue
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
}



EDIT Following from your comments, you might like to use a GeometryReader to measure the size of the bottom safe area inset, then you can compute how much extra padding to apply. This way, you can be sure that the button never goes into the safe area inset:
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Spacer()
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
                    .font(.fontRegular(size: 20))
                    .tint(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.DesignSystem.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            }
            .padding(.bottom, max(0, 100 - proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
        }
        .background(.black)
        .padding(.horizontal, 80)
        .padding(.top, 12)
        .background(Color.DesignSystem.background)
    }
}

In this version, the Color.DesignSystem.background color is applied to the VStack (after padding), so the ZStack is no longer needed.


oh, now i see, many thanks! didnt know that, I will test answer and then apply it here

my problem initially was that i wanted custom padding from bottom and when I've added it it was bigger then expected bc I don't know save area sizes, so I want to remove sfe area and then apply my padding from bottom

@МикитаШапко Answer updated with another version that allows the bottom padding to be set precisely, while also ensuring that the button never goes into the safe area inset

You can ignore safe area's bottom edge by adding this line to the VStack:
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)

Also, ZStack is redundant here as you can use .background(Color.DesignSystem.background) after .padding(.top, 12) on the VStack
So your code could look something like this:
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20){
        Spacer()
        
        Button {
        
        } label: {
            Text("Save")
                .tint(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.DesignSystem.blue)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        }
        
    }
    .background(.black)
    .padding(.horizontal, 80)
    .padding(.top, 12)
    .background(Color.DesignSystem.background)
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
}


as you can see vstack has black bg and it goes all the way to the bottom

I can see, but you still can add another .background(Color.DesignSystem.background) at the end instead of the ZStack
